# How do I align something alongside a document in a RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, position, height

This is a bit of an abstract question, but I can't really think of anywhere else to ask it.

I've got a Windows Store App with a RichText editor (utilizing the `RichEditBox` control)

It's a minimalist writing app, and I'd like to add a feature which allows a user to add margin notes to a document. The user would be able to add a margin note at any point in the doc, which would then be saved to a separate file. When they re-open the document they should then be able to scroll up and down and see the margin notes in the correct place.

So how do I do that? I've been racking my brain trying to figure out the best way to do this. RTF / Text files contain no line numbers. The safest thing I can think of is counting the number of words to the item, as this will allow me to get the rough position even if the editor changes width or font size. But two things are stumping me

Let's say I write a document 1000 words long. I add a note at a point 400 words in.

1) how do I map that "400 words in" to a vertical position on my "margin notes" grid? My best idea: I create an invisible, shadow RichEditBox of the same exact size, but with variable height. I put the first 400 words into it, then I measure the height of this box. I apply this height to the relevant note (probably as a margin offset). The issue I see with this is I can imagine it growing quite slow the more notes I add.

2) how do I account for editing? Suppose I go back and add 200 words before my note, how does my app know how many words have been added *before* a certain point? And wouldn't it have to re-run the above code with *every keystroke*, just to make sure the position of the notes are correct?

Note to mods: If this fits better in another Stack, please feel free to move it. Also there's currently no RichEditBox tag, so if someone with rep higher than 1500 wants to create it, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution**

Initially, things got quite complicated with me syncing the position of two `ScrollViewers` (one for the editor and one for the list of margin notes), adjusting heights etc. Eventually I realised I could just put my margin notes list and editor in the *same* `ScrollViewer`, and not have to sync anything.

Here's my XAML. I've removed anything not relevant.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="EditorScroller" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="MarginNotes" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   
             Margin="0,0,20,0"></Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <RichEditBox x:Name="MarginHelper" Opacity="0"
                 FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"></RichEditBox>        
            <!-- in a StackPanel so that the height is not set
                 note MarginHelper must have the exact 
                 same Width and FontSize as the editor,                      
                 even though MarginHelper is not visible  -->
        </StackPanel>            
        <RichEditBox x:Name="editor" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note that `MarginHelper` is inside a `StackPanel`. This means that it does not stretch to fill the `Grid`, and can be used to determine the height of the content

When the user presses CTRL+M, they are presented with a dialog that allows them to enter a note. The following code then attaches the note

```
private async Task AddMarginNote(string noteText)
{                    
    // get current cursor position
    int sPos = editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition;

    // select everything from the start of the document to the current position
    editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition = 0;
    editor.Document.Selection.EndPosition = sPos;

    // get selected text
    string text = "";
    editor.Document.Selection.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out text);

    // set MarginHelper text to selected text
    MarginHelper.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, text);

    // reset the editor selection 
    editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition = sPos;

    // measure height of MarginHelper 
    // (less 25 pixels, I'm not sure where this extra height is 
    // creeping in but its the only way to make this accurate)
    double mHeight = MarginHelper.ActualHeight - 25;

    // add a note to MarginNotes
    TextBlock note = new TextBlock();
    note.Text = noteText;
    note.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); 
    note.Margin = new Thickness { Top = mHeight }; 
    MarginNotes.Children.Add(note);        

    // save note to db
    // code here would store noteText along with text.Length for this document
}
```

I have yet to add code to actually save these notes anywhere, but I have tested loading them successfully, with the following code

```
private async void LoadNote(string noteText, int chars)
{
    // set selection 
    editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition = 0;
    editor.Document.Selection.EndPosition = chars;

    // get text
    string text = "";
    editor.Document.Selection.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out text);

    // set MarginHelper text
    MarginHelper.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, text);

    // measure height of MarginHelper
    double mheight = MarginHelper.ActualHeight - 25;

    // add a note to MarginNotes
    TextBlock note = new TextBlock();
    note.Text = noteText;
    note.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    note.Margin = new Thickness { Top = mheight };
    MarginNotes.Children.Add(note);
}
```

I'm still not sure how this will scale, but it seems to perform quite well for small to medium sized documents so far.

Also, I still haven't figured out how exactly to offset the saved notes when I edit text, but when I figure it out, I'll post the results here

This is fairly specific to my app, but there's a slight change it might come in handy to someone else at a later date, so I'm posting it.